# Unknown math.sqrt error

Tags: python, runtime-error

When I try this:

```
import math

g = input("Put your number here: ")

print ("The square root of you number is: " + int(math.sqrt(g)))
```

And I write `7` as my input per se, I get this error message:

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

I would greatly appreciate any solutions and or pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `TypeError` because `math.sqrt` requires a number (either a float or an integer):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(4.0)
2.0
>>> # Integers work too, even though the error message doesn't mention them
>>> math.sqrt(4)
2.0
>>> math.sqrt('4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
>>>
```

However, [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string object in Python 3.x:

```
>>> x = input()
7
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

This means that `g` will be a string when you give it to `math.sqrt`.

---

To fix the problem, you need to do two things:

1. Make `g` a number *before* giving it to `math.sqrt`.  This can be done with either [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#int) or [`float`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#float).
2. Convert the result back into a string to add it to the output string:

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> import math
>>> g = int(input("Put your number here: "))
Put your number here: 7
>>> print ("The square root of you number is: " + str(int(math.sqrt(g))))
The square root of you number is: 2
>>>
```

Note however that the last line can be rewritten a little more cleanly like so:

```
print ("The square root of you number is: %d" % math.sqrt(g))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
g = float(input("Put your number here: "))
```

With input() you get string, but float (or int) is needed.

Comment: Indeed. `sqrt("7")` makes as much sense as `sqrt("apple")` (unless you're a PHP dev).